# Formatting python dict with a for loop

Tags: json, python-3.x, for-loop, format

I am trying to write a for loop that goes through the `assets` (BTC, EOS) and the `available_balance` (0.00087168, 0). The `assets` work however I cannot get to the `available_balance`. How would I be able to get to it with json.

```
import json 

pairs= '''
({
  'ext_code': '',
  'rate_limit_status': 118,
  'result': {
      'BTC': {'available_balance': 0.00087168, 'cum_realised_pnl': 7.288e-05, 'equity': 0.00087168, 'given_cash': 0},
      'EOS': {'available_balance': 0, 'cum_realised_pnl': 0, 'equity': 0, 'given_cash': 0}
  },
  'ret_code': 0,
  'ret_msg': 'OK',
  'time_now': '1619987733.732306'}
<bravado.requests_client.RequestsResponseAdapter object at 0x000002D6F7FEB808>)
'''
data = json.loads(pairs)
Wallet_balance = data[0]['result']
for assets in balance:
    print("Asset: ", assets, " Balance: ", assets['available_balance'])
```

Expected Output:

```
Asset: BTC Balance: 0.00087168
Asset: EOS Balance: 0
```

The pprint Output:

```
({'ext_code': '',
  'ext_info': '',
  'rate_limit': 120,
  'rate_limit_reset_ms': 1620081183677,
  'rate_limit_status': 117,
  'result': {'BTC': {'available_balance': 0.00087168,
                     'cum_realised_pnl': 7.288e-05,
                     'equity': 0.00087168,
                     'given_cash': 0,
                     'occ_closing_fee': 0,
                     'occ_funding_fee': 0,
                     'order_margin': 0,
                     'position_margin': 0,
                     'realised_pnl': 0,
                     'service_cash': 0,
                     'unrealised_pnl': 0,
                     'used_margin': 0,
                     'wallet_balance': 0.00087168},
             'EOS': {'available_balance': 0,
                     'cum_realised_pnl': 0,
                     'equity': 0,
                     'given_cash': 0,
                     'occ_closing_fee': 0,
                     'occ_funding_fee': 0,
                     'order_margin': 0,
                     'position_margin': 0,
                     'realised_pnl': 0,
                     'service_cash': 0,
                     'unrealised_pnl': 0,
                     'used_margin': 0,
                     'wallet_balance': 0},
             'ETH': {'available_balance': 0.03362706,
                     'cum_realised_pnl': -7.41e-06,
                     'equity': 0.03362706,
                     'given_cash': 0,
                     'occ_closing_fee': 0,
                     'occ_funding_fee': 0,
                     'order_margin': 0,
                     'position_margin': 0,
                     'realised_pnl': 0,
                     'service_cash': 0,
                     'unrealised_pnl': 0,
                     'used_margin': 0,
                     'wallet_balance': 0.03362706},
             'USDT': {'available_balance': 0,
                      'cum_realised_pnl': 0,
                      'equity': 0,
                      'given_cash': 0,
                      'occ_closing_fee': 0,
                      'occ_funding_fee': 0,
                      'order_margin': 0,
                      'position_margin': 0,
                      'realised_pnl': 0,
                      'service_cash': 0,
                      'unrealised_pnl': 0,
                      'used_margin': 0,
                      'wallet_balance': 0},
             'XRP': {'available_balance': 0,
                     'cum_realised_pnl': 0,
                     'equity': 0,
                     'given_cash': 0,
                     'occ_closing_fee': 0,
                     'occ_funding_fee': 0,
                     'order_margin': 0,
                     'position_margin': 0,
                     'realised_pnl': 0,
                     'service_cash': 0,
                     'unrealised_pnl': 0,
                     'used_margin': 0,
                     'wallet_balance': 0}},
  'ret_code': 0,
  'ret_msg': 'OK',
  'time_now': '1620081183.700541'},
 <bravado.requests_client.RequestsResponseAdapter object at 0x0000016DC011F888>)
```

Comment: Does your "json" input use single quotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a heads up, your json is not valid. In addition to using single quotes, it is just missing parts.

Assuming you had either of the following, then this should get you going:

```
import json
import ast

## -----------------------------
## I have valid json
## -----------------------------
pairs_double_quoted = '''
[{
  "ext_code": "",
  "rate_limit_status": 118,
  "result": {
      "BTC": {"available_balance": 0.00087168, "cum_realised_pnl": 7.288e-05, "equity": 0.00087168, "given_cash": 0},
      "EOS": {"available_balance": 0, "cum_realised_pnl": 0, "equity": 0, "given_cash": 0}
  },
  "ret_code": 0,
  "ret_msg": "OK",
  "time_now": "1619987733.732306"
}]
'''
## -----------------------------

## -----------------------------
## I have something else that still looks hopeful
## -----------------------------
pairs_single_quoted = '''
({
  'ext_code': '',
  'rate_limit_status': 118,
  'result': {
      'BTC': {'available_balance': 0.00087168, 'cum_realised_pnl': 7.288e-05, 'equity': 0.00087168, 'given_cash': 0},
      'EOS': {'available_balance': 0, 'cum_realised_pnl': 0, 'equity': 0, 'given_cash': 0}
  },
  'ret_code': 0,
  'ret_msg': 'OK',
  'time_now': '1619987733.732306'
})
'''
## -----------------------------

## -----------------------------
## one or the other depending on if you have proper json (double) quotes
## -----------------------------
data = json.loads(pairs_double_quoted)
#data = [ast.literal_eval(pairs_single_quoted)]
## -----------------------------

## -----------------------------
## data is a list so we likely want to go though each item on the list
## if you only want the first item then use
## data_item = data[0]
## -----------------------------
for data_item in data:
    ## -----------------------------
    ## for each key value pair in the result dict print something
    ## -----------------------------
    for asset_key, asset_value in data_item["result"].items():
        print("Asset: {} Balance: {}".format(asset_key, asset_value["available_balance"]))
    ## -----------------------------
## -----------------------------
```

Based on your update that the data you have is exactly:

```
pairs_single_quoted = '''
({
  'ext_code': '',
  'rate_limit_status': 118,
  'result': {
      'BTC': {'available_balance': 0.00087168, 'cum_realised_pnl': 7.288e-05, 'equity': 0.00087168, 'given_cash': 0},
      'EOS': {'available_balance': 0, 'cum_realised_pnl': 0, 'equity': 0, 'given_cash': 0}
  },
  'ret_code': 0,
  'ret_msg': 'OK',
  'time_now': '1619987733.732306'
}<bravado.requests_client.RequestsResponseAdapter object at 0x000002D6F7FEB808>)
'''
```

for some reason, then you likely want to go the `ast` route:

```
import re
import ast

## -----------------------------
## I have something else that still looks hopeful
## -----------------------------
pairs_single_quoted = '''
({
    'ext_code': '',
    'ext_info': '',
    'rate_limit': 120,
    'rate_limit_reset_ms': 1620081183677,
    'rate_limit_status': 117,
    'result': {
        'BTC': {'available_balance': 0.00087168, 'cum_realised_pnl': 7.288e-05, 'equity': 0.00087168, 'given_cash': 0, 'occ_closing_fee': 0, 'occ_funding_fee': 0, 'order_margin': 0, 'position_margin': 0, 'realised_pnl': 0, 'service_cash': 0, 'unrealised_pnl': 0, 'used_margin': 0, 'wallet_balance': 0.00087168},
        'EOS': {'available_balance': 0, 'cum_realised_pnl': 0, 'equity': 0, 'given_cash': 0, 'occ_closing_fee': 0, 'occ_funding_fee': 0, 'order_margin': 0, 'position_margin': 0, 'realised_pnl': 0, 'service_cash': 0, 'unrealised_pnl': 0, 'used_margin': 0, 'wallet_balance': 0},
        'ETH': {'available_balance': 0.03362706, 'cum_realised_pnl': -7.41e-06, 'equity': 0.03362706, 'given_cash': 0, 'occ_closing_fee': 0, 'occ_funding_fee': 0, 'order_margin': 0, 'position_margin': 0, 'realised_pnl': 0, 'service_cash': 0, 'unrealised_pnl': 0, 'used_margin': 0, 'wallet_balance': 0.03362706}
    },
    'ret_code': 0,
    'ret_msg': 'OK',
    'time_now': '1620081183.700541'},
    <bravado.requests_client.RequestsResponseAdapter object at 0x0000016DC011F888>)
 '''
## -----------------------------

## -----------------------------
## a regex wizard would do this via re.sub()
## -----------------------------
pattern = re.compile(r"^(.*),.*<bravado.*$", re.DOTALL)
text_in = re.findall(pattern, pairs_single_quoted)[0] + ")"
data = [ast.literal_eval(text_in)]
## -----------------------------

## -----------------------------
## data is a list so we likely want to go though each item on the list
## if you only want the first item then use
## data_item = data[0]
## -----------------------------
for data_item in data:
    ## -----------------------------
    ## for each key value pair in the result dict print something
    ## -----------------------------
    for asset_key, asset_value in data_item["result"].items():
        print("Asset: {} Balance: {}".format(asset_key, asset_value["available_balance"]))
    ## -----------------------------
## -----------------------------
```

This should result in:

```
Asset: BTC Balance: 0.00087168
Asset: EOS Balance: 0
Asset: ETH Balance: 0.03362706
```

Comment: I have updated the issue, I forgot to place `<bravado.requests_client.RequestsResponseAdapter object at 0x000002D6F7FEB808>` at the end of the json dict. I am getting the error: `TypeError: 'RequestsResponseAdapter' object is not subscriptable. If you could take a look at it I would appreciate it. 
`

Comment: It says tuple object has no atribute split on the editted code

Comment: I am, getting the `pairs_single_quoted ` as type `tuple` instead of type `string ` since I am getting it from a webserver.

Comment: I guess I would need to see exactly the text returned as at the moment It looks like what i have is not what you are getting back. For example, is there actually a comma prior to the `<bravado.requests_client` by any chance?

Comment: Sorry for the trouble yea I will just update the whole json output with `pprint` so you could see the whole thing

Comment: I tried to type cast `pairs_single_quoted ` to string but it messes it up since the values must be inetegres and not strings

Comment: Were you able to take a look at the updated issue by any chance?

Comment: Yes, sorry I put an edit in yesterday. use the second (ast) version that now has a regex that picks out the part you want to parse

Comment: It gives me an error for the `text_in` variable , `TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object`. The problem is that the `pairs_single_quoted` is of type tuple in my one since I am getting it from a webserver and your one is of type string. I cant really type cast it since it turns the integer values into strings.